# Is there a way to run my love2d game without installing love2d itself?

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm making a game using LOVE2D and I'm almost finished. However, I'm worried; can the user install the game without even installing Love2d itself? If so how can I extract it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The distribution of games created by you is documented in this page: [Love2D - Game Distribution](http://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution).

In short, when you want to distribute a game, you can simply package it in `.zip` and rename it to a `.love`. Running this requires that the user has Love2D installed.

However, you can also create a self-executable package from your game, this means that you will distribute a single executable and the users do not have to install anything. This is also documented in the page.